# Separar una funcion de una ruta node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, async-await

Tengo la siguiente ruta y funciona perfectamente

```
router.get('/api/User/:id',async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const{id}=req.params;
    let result =await pool1.request()
      .input('Iduser', sql.Int, id)
      .execute('GetUser')
      res.json(result);
  } 
    catch (err) {
      res.json({ error: 'Does Not exist' })
    }
});
```

Pero quiero seperar la funcion para dejar la ruta lo más limpia posible incluso creo que es lo recomendado, intente separarlo de la siguiente manera para que toda la logica y el manejo de errores quede en la funcion y solo mandarla llamar desde la ruta, pero me arroja el siguiente error al buscar por el id: `TypeError: one is not a function`

Ruta

```
router.get('/api/User/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        res.json((await one(req.params.id))[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
})
```

Funcion

```
const one = async(id)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    pool.request()
      .input('Iduser', sql.Int, id)
      .execute('User')((err,results) =>{
          if(err){
              return reject(err);
          }
          resolve(results);
      });

    });
}
```

Comment: El tema sería donde estas declarando `one`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre cual era el problema estaba llamando dos metodos por separado asi:

```
const one = require('../metod')
const edit = require('../metod')
```

Cuando debi hacer esto

```
const mdt = require('../metod')
```

Y llamar al metodo one y los demas metodos de esta manera:

```
router.get('/api/User/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        let result=await **mdt.one**(req.params.id);
        res.json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
})
```

Funcion

```
const one = async(id)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         pool.request()
        .input('IdUser', sql.Int, id)
        .execute('GetUser',(err,results)=>{
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
                resolve(results);
        }
        )    
    });
}
```